# Going further with C for iOS development

Tags: c, ios

I am an experienced iOS developer amongst other things. I have a good mastery of Objective-C and Apple's frameworks in the language.

But when it comes to the C-based frameworks I often hit a ceiling with my knowledge, and often have to look up idioms and syntax. I learnt C from K&R but it's been a while. I did try learning from it again and it was a blast; but by Chapter 6, I got a feeling that its C is a bit archaic, at least idiom-wise. Also, I want to learn C mostly for the sake of iOS development and so a Mac/iOS focused learning process would be ideal.

What will be a good way to go about doing this?

Comment: `Objective C != C`

Comment: @Robert: Of course, but it's a super-set. So you could do a chunk of iOS development in C if you really wanted to. In any case, several iOS/Mac frameworks are purely in C.

Comment: Which C-based frameworks, exactly, are you using for iOS development?

Comment: Core Audio, Address Book, and Core Foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest just **doing**; just code all kinds of sample projects on Mac using C and C-based frameworks. That's the real way of dealing with coding C under Mac. Then you can ask more specific questions to help you going forward.